# Help display image in single post using javascript zoom image..?

Tags: javascript

Can someone helping me implement single post image with Javascript features with image zoom such i found here : http://www.housetohome.co.uk/galleries/bedroom/adult/Relaxed_country_bedroom_31391.html

Thanks

max

Comment: Can you show us the code so far so that we can see where you're going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The site you linked to uses paid script [Magic Zoom Plus, it has WordPress plugin available](http://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoomplus/modules/wordpress/).